# how to display geojson data on a leaflet map

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am trying to display the coordinates I have saved in JSON format on a leaflet map. Neither the marker of the coordinates is showing nor am I getting any error. here is my `geojson` data and the code that should display the records on the map. Where might I be doing it wrong?

```
var geoJsondata = {
            "type": "FeatureCollection",
            "features": [
                {
                    "type": "Feature",
                    "properties": {
                        "name": "Example 1",
                        "amenity": "Baseball Stadium",
                        "iconSize": [50, 50],
                        "locationId": 1,
                        "image": "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1688976694262-89230d6133ba?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHw3fHx8ZW58MHx8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60",
                        "popupContent": "This is where the Rockies play!"
                    },
                    "geometry": {
                        "type": "Point",
                        "coordinates": [-1.2822121651282061, 36.82157993316651]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "type": "Feature",
                    "properties": {
                        "name": "Example 2",
                        "amenity": "Baseball Stadium",
                        "iconSize": [50, 50],
                        "locationId": 2,
                        "image": "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1688728981543-df24d24d0116?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwyNXx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60",
                        "popupContent": "This is where the Rockies play!"
                    },
                    "geometry": {
                        "type": "Point",
                        "coordinates": [-1.2842580516508735, 36.816703677177436]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "type": "Feature",
                    "properties": {
                        "name": "Example 3",
                        "amenity": "Baseball Stadium",
                        "iconSize": [50, 50],
                        "locationId": 3,
                        "image": "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1688966838599-05e6cf6628cf?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwzMnx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60",
                        "popupContent": "This is where the Rockies play!"
                    },
                    "geometry": {
                        "type": "Point",
                        "coordinates": [-1.2815256914612605, 36.81707382202149]
                    }
                }
                
            ]
        }

        L.geoJSON(geoJsondata).addTo(map);
```

i tried using this code but i get an marker is not defined

````
var loadLocations = () =>{
            geoJsondata.features.forEach((location) => {
                var {geometry,properties } = location
                var {iconSize,locationId,name,amenity,image,popupContent } = properties

                let markerElement = document.createElement('div')

                markerElement.className = 'marker' + locationId
                markerElement.id = locationId
                // marker.style.backgroundImage = 'url(https://www.flaticon.com/free-icon/maps-and-flags_447031?term=google+maps&page=1&position=1&origin=tag&related_id=447031)'
                // marker.style.backgroundSize = 'cover'
                // marker.style.width = '50px'
                // marker.style.height = '50px'

                new L.Marker(markerElement)
                .setLngLat(geometry.coordinates).addTo(map)
            })
        }

        loadLocations()```
````